# Extract indices of multiple elements from 2D Numpy array, Python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have one 2D numpy array

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[7, 7, 7],
              [4, 7, 7],
              [4, 0, 0]])
```

I extracted y which is

```
y = [4 4]
```

Now I want to extract the Indices of [4 4] in x

I am using the following method

```
indices = np.argwhere(x == y)
```

which results `[[1 0][2 0]`

But in some cases, this code fails. would you please suggest any other way to perform the same task

Comment: `x==y` doesn't work, does it?  `x==4` is a boolean where `x` is 4.  `np.nonzero(x==4)` is a tuple of indices where that is true.  `x[x==4]` produces `y`.  `np.argwhere(x==4)` is similar to the `nonzero`, but the indices aren't quite as useful.  You can also do `x[1:, 0]` to get `y`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `nonzero()`

```
indices = np.nonzero(x == 4)
# (array([1, 2]), array([0, 0]))
```

[Numpy Documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)